# How to change IN operator with CHARINDEX within the WHERE clause SQL

Tags: sql, charindex, in-operator

I have these query :

```
SELECT *
FROM   
    Table_a A
    JOIN Table_b B
        ON (B.ID = A.ID)
WHERE
    (A.UserLogin = @UserLogin)
    AND (B.ID IN @DocumentID)
```

And I want to change using Charindex :

```
SELECT *
FROM   
    Table_a A
    JOIN Table_b B
        ON (B.ID = A.ID)
WHERE
    (A.UserLogin = @UserLogin)
    AND CHARINDEX(@DocumentID, B.ID ) > 0)
```

But the value of @DocumentID='3,4,5'. I don't know how to use CHARINDEX in this case. Can someone help... Thanks

Comment: [Parameterize an SQL IN clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterize-an-sql-in-clause)

Comment: Do it right, use table-valued parameter.

Comment: @lad2025 I don't think so. I think I need to make little change in the CHARINDEX statement. But I don't know how...

Comment: So, the CHARINDEX can accept more than 1 value of @DocumentID.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13534053/5070879 with `CHARINDEX` version and [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/31994/3)